# Externalizing JPA Mappings Configuration

Tags: jpa

I would like to externalize the value of schema element from JPA mappings XML and read it from a properties file. The value of schema is xx_yy_${env.USERNAME}. It doesn't work if I put it directly into my mapping file. Is there a way to externalise it ?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working now. Was able to do this using the maven filtering plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I put another solution with creating views. So you have fixed names in schema and DB configuration remap it to actual tables.

See [JPA, externalizing column, table or schema names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978242/jpa-externalizing-column-table-or-schema-names)

I can't filter sources and have 20 different builds ((